# How to get a specific number of random integers in Java

Tags: java, random

I need to get 4 to 8 different pairs (x,y) of integers from set {0,1,2,3,4} and to write members of one 2D array on position (x,y) to other.
I tried it this way below but it doesn't work.

```
int ra =nextRandomNumber();
    int nu = (ra%5) + 4;

int c=0;
int [] poss= new int[8];


while(c<nu){
        int p =nextRandomNumber();
        int q =nextRandomNumber();
        int x=p%5 ;
        int y=q%5;
        int m=10*x+y;
        int co=0;
    for(int i=0; i<c; i++){
        if(m!=poss[i])
                co+=1;
        }
        if (co==c+1){
            poss[c]=m;
    frame.getLabel().getLabelTable()[x][y]
                    .setText("" + tabla[x][y]);
    c+=1;
}
    }
        }
```

where I created nextRandomNumber by:

```
private static int nextRandomNumber(){
    long curr = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int p = (int) (curr%120);
    return p;
}
```

I hope you understand what I want and that you can help me.

I did what Sibbo advised me and now I have full table, but I need only 4-8 numbers in it. So I tried to solve in on way below, but it still gives me full table.

```
Random ra =new Random();
    int nu=ra.nextInt(5)+4;

    Set<Pair> alreadyUsed = new HashSet<Pair>();
    Pair result;

    do {
        result = new Pair(ra.nextInt(5), ra.nextInt(5));
      frame.getLabel().getLabelTable()[result.getX()][result.getY()]
        .setText("" + tabla[result.getX()][result.getY()]);
    }while (!alreadyUsed.contains(result)&&alreadyUsed.size()<nu);

    alreadyUsed.add(result);
}
```

I solved the problem by using the code below. Thank you all for help.

```
Random ra =new Random();
Random r1 =new Random();
Random r2 =new Random();
    int nu=ra.nextInt(5)+4;
    boolean [][] exists= new boolean [5][5];
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
            exists [i][j]=false;
        }
    }
    int c=0;
    while (c<nu){
        int p=r1.nextInt(5);
        int q=r2.nextInt(5);
        if(exists[p][q]==false){
            frame.getLabel().getLabelTable()[p][q]
                .setText("" + tabla[p][q]);
            exists[p][q]=true;
            c+=1;
        }
    }
        }
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not helpful...

Comment: When you say "it doesnt work" please explain what doesn't work. What you expect and what you get.

Comment: Is it just me or `specific number of random integers` sounds a little bit clumsy?

Comment: By "it doesn't work" I meant that no numbers are written in table of labels (getLabelTable()[x][y])

Comment: A milli-second is a very long time and it will take you a very long time to generate all the different random numbers (actually they won't be very random as you will get sequential numbers)

Comment: I used the nextRandomNumber() method for generating a futoshiki-valid table so I planed to use it to generate 4 to 8 numbers inside of table at the beginning of the game.

Comment: Please check my answer.... if you essentially want to select randomly 4-8 points (x,y) from the 16 total combinations this can easily be done by shuffling randomly the list of points and selecting the first 4 to 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get random numbers, use the `Random` class:

```
Random r = new Random();

r.nextInt(5); // Returns a random integer between 0 and 4 inclusive.
```

To get distinct random numbers, use a set with them:

```
Set<Pair<Integer>> alreadyUsed = new HashSet<Pair<Integer>>(); // You have to write the pair class yourself.
```

Now generate the numbers like this:

```
Pair<Integer> result;

do {
    result = new Pair<Integer>(r.nextInt(5), r.nextInt(5));
while (!alreadyUsed.contains(result);

alreadyUsed.add(result);
```

Comment: And in your answer, where do I use the fact that I need 4 to 8 distinct pairs? I'm a complete beginner in Java (programming at all) so I apologise for asking to many questions.

Comment: I did what you say and now I have full table, but I need only 4-8 numbers in it. So I tried to solve in on way below, but it still gives me full table.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific problem you can easily use something like the following:

```
    Random random = new Random();
    List<Point> pairs = new ArrayList<Point>();
    List<Point> resultPairs;

    for(int x=1; x<5; x++)for(int y=1; y<5; y++)
    pairs.add(new Point(x,y));          

    Collections.shuffle(pairs, random); 
    resultPairs = pairs.subList(0, 4+random.nextInt(5)); //take 4 to 8 elements 

//Debug-print out lists
    System.out.println("Initial Points");
    for(Point p: pairs)System.out.println("("+p.x+","+p.y+")");

    System.out.println("Random Points " + resultPairs.size());
    for(Point p: resultPairs)System.out.println("("+p.x+","+p.y+")");
```

We create a list of all the available pairs with x and y (16 different combinations) and then shuffle the list randomly.

Then we simply take the sublist of X(4 to 8) elements that we want.

Applied to your code this would make:

```
//Do the GUI operations
for(Point p: resultPairs)
frame.getLabel().getLabelTable()[p.x][p.y].setText("" + tabla[p.x][p.y]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your code and trace through your logic, then trace through Sibbo's logic. You have made a fundamental change in the logic here.

Basically, you need to add the line

```
frame.getLabel().getLabelTable()[result.getX()][result.getY()].setText("" + tabla[result.getX()][result.getY()]);
```

after the last line of Sibbo's code. Then surround the whole block with some kind of counter, to tell you when you have your 4-8 results.

You'll also need to think about how you're going to decide you have enough results. Computers don't like vague things like "4-8". Do want some random number of results? Do you want to have an optimal number of tries, stopping if you get to 8 first and continuing if you don't have at least 4? Or is 4 good enough? Something else? This will determine what type of counter you use.

Comment: I tried to take random integer in range 4-8 (int nu=ra.nextInt(5)+4;) for enough number of results.

Comment: Okay, so take that number and use it in a for loop for your counter. But you still need to revamp your logic.